# Why isn't the set timeout function activating the win statement?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The task I want my program to complete successfully is for it to intake a value from the command prompt variable `ask` and check if it was correct. But if the player doesn't answer in time, the set timeout function would execute therefore subtracting a life.

My problem is when I enter the prompt `ask` the timeout function isn't setting off at all.

Also, I have the whole thing in a for-loop so when the player does get the answer correct, it runs again and subtracts the time so there is less and less time to solve the problem. My code is below.

```
var win = null;
var product = "123456";
time = 3000;

for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    confirm("Round will start after you close this confirm window.");

    setTimeout(function() {
        var ask = prompt("Enter code below: (QUICK) " + product + " (Answer for development purposes)"); 

        if(ask === product){
            win = true;
            console.log("Hurrah!");
        } else {
            win = false;
            console.log("Arr. Well get em next time.");
        }
    }, 1);

    //Why is this not activating???
    setTimeout(function() { 
        if (win === null || false) {
            lives = lives - 1;
            win = false;

            console.log("Oh No! You ran out of time. Lives left: " + lives);
        }
    }, time);  

    time = time - 100;    
}
```

Comment: What is `lives`? Also, `win === null || false` should be `win === null || win === false` or else it will never execute

Comment: `prompt()` simply doesn't support a timeout and because it's a blocking function, nothing else can run until it's done.

Comment: do you want a javascript only solution for this. Beacuse whatever @jfriend00 has commented is the reason for your problem. And jQuery can solve your problem easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prompt()` is a blocking function that does not return until the user supplies the required input.  Because it is blocking, no other Javascript runs while it is waiting for the user input.  Thus, your `setTimeout()` cannot run while `prompt()` is waiting for input.

So, because it's blocking and it doesn't have a built-in timeout capability, you can't use `prompt()` to do what you're trying to do.  It simply doesn't have that capability and the blocking nature of that function prevents you from using a `setTimeout()` to make the time out feature work.

Assuming this is in a web page, you could use a different form of non-blocking prompt (such as form elements on a web page).  In that case, you could both present the input elements asking for user input and use a `setTimeout()` that would fire if no input was provided.  Because the user interface in that case was non-blocking, other Javascript could run while this UI was presented to the user and you could implement your timeout that way.  You would also have to change your code to work off event handlers instead of a blocking `prompt()` function.

Comment: @Bubblegumz - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the if statement in your second timeout will never be executed. you can try this

```
if(win == null || win == false){

                    lives = lives - 1;
                    win = false;

                    console.log("Oh No! You ran out of time. Lives left: " + lives);
                }
```